# c# use non-printable characters asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unicode, special-characters

I've to read datamatrix barcodes (vda 4902, gtin, gs1) which use non-printable chars as seperator.
The goal is to scan the barcode with intermec or honeywell hardware and send it to a c# mvc webapplication. 
The printable characters are received by the webapplication, but the non-printable chars not.
I've scanned the code to the VI editor on a linux server - bere i can see the special characters. But i couldn't get it with a asp.net to work nor a c# windows form application.

So currently i don't know where to look at...

Comment: Without sample code that demonstrates how you send data to web site and how your read that data with ASP.Net MVC there is no way to suggest anything about your post.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if you are passing values to another page or webservice, you are forgetting the step of properly encoding the characters you are sending. You should probably look at using something like System.Web.HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode. This function properly converts special characters in the value you are sending to an alternate representation that gets decoded on the receiving end.

Depending on other specifics would you did not elaborate on your original question, there are many other ways to encode/escape characters for purposes like this. But the above is what I would suggest starting with if you are not clear.